# Subset of features on external memory

Tags: r, large-data, xgboost

I have a large file that I'm not able to load so I'm using a local file with `xgb.DMatrix`. But I'd like to use only a subset of the features. The documentation on `xgboost` says that the `colset` argument on `slice` is "currently not used" and there is no metion of this feature in the github page. And I haven't found any other clue of how to do column subsetting with external memory.

I wish to compare models generated with different features subsettings. The only thing I could think of is to create a new file with the features that I want to use but it's taking a long time and will take a lot of memory... I can't help wondering if there is a better way.

ps.: I tried using `h2o` package too but `h2o.importFile` froze.

Comment: You could store your data in a sqlite database. Then you can write a query to only load a subset of the data into R.

Comment: Hi ALex, thank you for the response but my data is too big... I don't have enough RAM to load it into R, even if it's only a subset of my features...

Comment: You can do with the subset whatever you want. You don't have to read it into R. You can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Xgboost supports that?

Comment: How did you create the `xgb.DMatrix` file? Do the same with the subset.

Comment: I pass the name of the file, but `xgb.DMatrix` only supports libsvm files.